# Execute a php file with VBA code every two minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, vba

I have to **export data from ACCESS** using **VBA** code to **EXCEL XLS files**.
After that i have to **execute a php script with VBA** code to "refactor" the data and put them in a **MySQL database attached to HeidiSQL SGBD**.

**But i have the following problem :**

> I'm exporting data of every table every 2 minutes and i have to call the php script just after that to update MySQL database.
> How can i call the code that execute the php script when the data export is finish to avoid a conflict ? (with another timer ?)

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
  On Error Resume Next
  If Me.B_minuterie.Visible = True Then
    Me.B_minuterie.Visible = False
  Else
    Me.B_minuterie.Visible = True
  End If
  cheminDossierExports = "xxx"
  cheminFichierClients = cheminDossierExports + "\xxx.xls"
  cheminFichierJeux = cheminDossierExports + "\xxx.xls"
  cheminFichierEditeurs = cheminDossierExports + "\xxx.xls"
  cheminFichierEmprunts = cheminDossierExports + "\xxx.xls"

  DoEvents

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 5, "req_export_tClient", cheminFichierClients, True

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 5, "req_export_tJeu", cheminFichierJeux, True

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 5, "req_export_tEditeur", cheminFichierEditeurs, True

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 5, "req_export_tEmprunt", cheminFichierEmprunts, True

  DoEvents
```

> I want to execute the code at the bottom that run the php script when the code at the top has finished running

> How can i do that ?

```
'sample url address
 Const url As String = "xxx"
 Dim urlText As String
 With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
 End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: That didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: I.e. there is some data in .MDB or .ACCDB. You export this data to .XLS or .XLSX (using VBA macros). Then you import this data to MySQL (using PHP script). Is it?

Comment: @TimWilliams the code works, but this part of the code (when i call the .php script 'sample url address ) is to slow and plant the program.

Comment: @Akina yes it is. and the part when i call the .php script plant the program.

Comment: How long does your PHP script take to run?  Are you checking the PHP output in your VBA or you just want to start the process then let it run?  You can call the PHP asynchronously `.Open "GET", url, True` but you will need to make your XMLHTTP object a Global so it doesn't go out of scope when `Form_Timer` exits.  See http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/ if you want to make an async call and still handle the response.

Comment: If so then export data not to XLS but to CSV. Then import data with LOAD DATA INFILE statement executed via Php script or Event scheduler procedure.

Comment: @TimWilliams I  found an alternative solution but its good to know that thank you !